# Extend data object that is passed to Vue component with shared methods/props

Tags: vue.js

this is my first Vue question as I am still learning.

So let's say I have this component:

```
Vue.component('list-card', {
    props: ['entry'],
    computed: {
        isArchived: function() { return this.entry.Status == 'Archived' }
    },
    template: `<div class="card">
        <span class="icon" :style="{ opacity: isArchived ? 0.2 : 1 }"></span>
    </div>`
});
```

Now, I want to extract the method isArchived because I may have other similar components that render the card - grid-card, board-card, etc... and they all will need the isArchived which is not in the entry object.

To me, the problem is that the entry object being passed to the component is a POJO - plain data object with no methods or computed properties. So I have to define the property on the component itself, not the data object. Which is wrong from my OOP experience - the entry.IsArchived() or entry.IsArchived prop would make more sense.

Now, I can extend this object before passing the entry object to the component, or even when getting the entries in some store, etc. But I don't want to do that - 1. Only components should know if they need isArchived or not, and 2. This affects performance - component may decide not to use isArchived but I already calculated that.

So what's the proper VueJS way to solve this?

Comment: I suggest to try to avoid adding too much logic related to the project business into a reusing component. For example, you can provide an `isArchived` prop of type boolean, and only pass in logic related to `isArchived` when the parent component uses the child component

Comment: That goes against both of my points: 1. the parent component should not care if the card UI changes based on the archived state (or any other prop) 2. the parent component should not pre-calculate the isArchived prop because it may not even be used by the child - the parent should not know the child rendering details. So pre-calculating props for the child component means not only more boilerplate code, but also more tight coupling. E.g. if the child decides to change its rendering, we'll have to change all parents who uses it.

Comment: Found a request for the same feature: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1964

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) said, `Mixins are a flexible way to distribute reusable functionalities for Vue components`, so you can use the [mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)

```
// define a mixin object
var myMixin = {
   props: ['entry'],
    computed: {
        isArchived: function() { return this.entry.Status == 'Archived' }
   },
}

// define a component that uses this mixin
var Component = Vue.extend({
  mixins: [myMixin],
  template: `<div class="card">
        <span class="icon" :style="{ opacity: isArchived ? 0.2 : 1 }"></span>
    </div>`
})

var component = new Component() // => "hello from mixin!"
```

Comment: So, basically, like extracting the entry object interface into a mixin - kind of a partial C# class? Then, what is different components have a different entry name - e.g. one use "entry" and another use "card"?

Comment: Nevermind, I read the docs and I see I can pass the prop (entry) name to mixin. So this looks like a good solution but I hesitate for two reasons: 1. I saw it is considered anti-pattern e.g. see https://css-tricks.com/how-the-vue-composition-api-replaces-vue-mixins/ 2. For this reason I am not sure that mixins are really the "proper Vue way".

Comment: E.g. let's say I have a component that is passed two entries - oldCard and newCard. I can pass those names to the two mixins added to the component but mixin's computed prop will be always isArchived for both card objects - as far as I understand. So Vue3 solves this problem with the Composition API but I wonder if there's a better way in Vue2.

Comment: As you said, Composition API in Vue3 is the better way. But in Vue2, the way is the mixins